# How can I coat a garage apron slab to make it smoother?

Tags: flooring, paint

I'd like to smooth out a square concrete slab at the front of the garage. This concrete serves as a part of a driveway. The floor coating needs to cover the gaps and offer a smooth surface for rollerblading.

I was thinking using some type of Epoxy coating but I'm not sure if Epoxy is the right solution for rollerblading. What would be the best coating to use that can withstand cars driving over it and also offer smooth treatment for rollerblading?

[image]

Comment: @isherwood, there aren't cracks only gaps that you add when you make concrete.

Comment: @isherwood, I just want to make it suitable for roller skating but also still having cars driving on it.

Comment: @isherwood, ideally both. The concrete has no any damage or cracks. I just want to make it smooth so I don't keep tripping on it when skating. Especially on joint gaps.

Answer (score 1):

There is a product called "concrete resurfacer" which I would vaguely equate to "the concrete version of asphalt driveway sealer" - don't use asphalt driveway sealer on concrete...

You first patch any actual damage, then mix up the resurfacer into a slurry of specified consistency, and squeegee it onto the dampened slab to fill in the minor imperfections. You can give it a finish from troweled smooth to brushed non-slip.

These products should not be used to fill expansion joints - those can be filled with flexible rubber caulking compounds made for the job, if filling them is required.

Comment: Are there any tutorials, instructions or pictures?

Comment: Yes. Since I don't want to play spammer for any particular product, try searching on the term and visit manufacturer's websites.

Comment: Is this cheaper than using a concrete grinder? I think it cost around $160 to rent in home depot.

Comment: That's firstly a shopping question, which is off-topic, and secondly a question that would involve the area and depth of defects (neither quantified) as well as how you count or value your time. Once you have quantified the area and depth of defects to arrive at calculated coverage, it becomes a question you can answer for yourself by checking the local price for both options. Of course, if you make it too smooth you may have trouble with cars skidding, particularly when wet.